# LinearLayout ImageView pushes views off screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview

So for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what seems to be a simple layout problem. I was hoping maybe a fresh pair of eyes could help me out.

**The Issue:** I have three views in a vertical LinearLayout.

- A TextView
- An ImageView that needs to preserve its aspect ratio with AdjustViewBounds set to true and wrap content. (The aspect ratio appears to be broken if a layout weight is set to the ImageView)
- Another TextView

I can't use custom views as this is for a Widget.

***The problem is when the available space is too small the ImageView pushes the bottom TextView outside of the screen where the expected result I'm looking for is the ImageView resizes to accommodate both TextViews keeping them both inside the viewing area as long as possible. I can get this desired effect with a layout weight set to the ImageView but for some reason this breaks the aspect ratio.***
Expected result on the left. However loses aspect ratio when dimensions are to tall.
[image]

**The Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/sunny"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Examples:**

**TextView being pushed out of screen while ImageView is not resizing to accommodate it:**
[image]

**ImageView is set to `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_height="0dp"`. It now resizes to accommodate the bottom TextView as desired however loses its aspect ratio:**
[image]

**ImageView is set to `layout_weight="1"`, `layout_height="0dp"`, and `scaleType="fitCenter"`. This preserves the aspect ratio while still resizing to accommodate the bottom TextView. However there is extra whitespace and the TextView is no longer close to the image.** 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully I explained the issue sufficiently. Thank you :)!

Nathan

Comment: What do you need exactly to be show ? not getting exactly from your question. Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/sunny"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this creates something similar to the second image in my post. The aspect ratio is not preserved and the TextView at the top has a lot of extra whitespace between it and the actual image.